# Reconhecer loop for de outros scripts python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando escrever um script python que possa reconher qualquer boucle for em outros scripts python.

```
import re

with open('boite_a_fonctions_v3_1.py', 'r') as f:
    text=f.read()
    a = text.split(" ")
    #print (a)

    boucle = re.compile(r'for"(.*):\t(.*)"')

    def recherche_boucle(a):
        c = []
        for linha in a:
            c += boucle.findall(linha)
        print (c)

    #recherche_boucle (a)
```

Não tenho nada como resultado (o que já me deixa feliz, pelo menos não há erros!!). Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Ah, uma parte do código 'boite_a_fonctions_v3_1.py':

```
fidr.seek(0)
reg = compile(fmt.get_motif())
id = 0
for line in fidr :
# par ligne
    for seg in reg.findall(line) :
    # par token
        if id == tokenId :
            mot, etq = seg
            return mot, etq
        else :
            id += 1
return None

def get_tokens(fid, fmt, tokenIds):
    if isinstance(tokenIds, int):
        try :
            return get_token(fid,fmt, tokenIds)
        except :
return None
else:
    n = None
    for id in tokenIds:
        try:
            n = len(get_token(fid,fmt, id))
            break
        except:
            pass
    if not n :
        return None

    ret = list()
    for i in range(n) :
        tmp = list()
        for id in tokenIds :
            try:
                tmp.append(get_token(fid,fmt,id)[i])
            except:
                pass
        ret.append(tmp)
    return ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na minha opinião não é bom declares uma função dentro de um ficheiro aberto, (funciona mas acho que não é boa prática).

Podes fazer assim:

```
import re

def recherche_boucle():
    boucle = re.compile('^\s*for (.*?):')
    with open('boite_a_fonctions_v3_1.py', 'r') as f:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            match = boucle.match(line)
            if match:
                yield (line_num, match.group(1))

for line_num, boucle in recherche_boucle():
    print('descoberto ciclo for na linha {}: {}'.format(line_num, boucle))
```

Se quiseres a linha do `for` encontrado por inteiro e não só o que está entre `for` e `:`, podes trocar `...group(1)` por `...group(0)`, ou se quiseres a linha por inteiro (neste caso vai dar ao mesmo que `...group(0)`) podes trocar `yield (line_num, match.group(1))` por `yield (line_num, line)`

Esta função retorna um gerador, ou seja para teres uma lista dos resultados podes `list(recherche_boucle())`

Solução sem regex:

```
def recherche_boucle():
    with open('boite_a_fonctions_v3_1.py', 'r') as f:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if all(match in line for match in ('for ', ':')): # se na linha existe for e :
                yield (line_num, line.strip()) # strip para tirar as quebras de linha

for line_num, boucle in recherche_boucle():
    print('descoberto ciclo for na linha {}: {}'.format(line_num, boucle))
```

Comment: Miguel, obrigada! Brilhante, espero um dia ter 1% do seu talento em python :)

Comment: Hehe @pitanga, como em qualquer linguagem a prática faz o mestre, e no caso de python é relativamente simples. Treino/brincar com código é importante